# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

I don't have enough reputation to comment, and apparently I can't answer broad / bland question in poor limericks... Here's the answer in, uhh, question!

[Define theme information other than through style.css](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173317/define-theme-information-other-than-through-style-css/173319?noredirect=1#comment252005_173319)

This was a broad question which was answered with links to helpful resources in which the user can edit their content using filters / hook OR better their question by actually taking the tour and adding more detail.

Why was my answer deleted exactly whenever it wasn't necessarily unhelpful?

Answer (score 6):

I deleted your answer, because it was at best an overly broad comment. The *question* is clear and specific, answers should follow the same scheme. You made no attempt to solve the problem, you just posted some very generic, and in this case: misleading, links. This doesn’t qualify as an answer.

Comment: :/ here I can add a comment, but OK - if you won't accept Limericks as an answer I'm of no use here. Challenge to future readers though:::::: Answer a question in a complete Limerick and get accepted and one day I'll give you a bounty!

Comment: I don’t care whether you write a limerick or the next Nibelungenlied. But I do care about the **content** of your answers, and in this case the content required deletion.